# Story about a spaceport gas station and a "Book of Mormon" type pioneer family on new planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a longer story or novelette.

It begins with the POV of a gas station worker watching families go to a space transit port.  Each family will be transported to their own planet.

The POV then shifts to one of the families, a husband with multiple wives.  They get to their new planet and begin building.

The husband is not very good and I think in the end he dies and the oldest wife takes over.  I could be wrong because I found the gas station bit at the beginning much more engrossing than the pioneering itself.  Because I have worked overnights in gas stations and have seen some stuff.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and approximately when did you read this?  Was it in a magazine, an anthology or online?

Comment: Do you recall what kind of equipment the settlers take with them?  Are they in spaceships, trucks, wagons?  How big are the groups?  Is the planet already settled when they arrive?

Comment: Not an answer, but your description is giving me "Tunnel In The Sky" Heinlein vibes. It's not, because there's no gas station and no follow-up of the pioneers' stories, but the way you describe it reminds me of the ending of that novel.

Comment: @Seneca I got Heinlein vibes as well, probably because of the 'multiple wives' thing in the question

Comment: @Danny-Mc-G Heinlein loved the Mormons, wrote them into several stories as hard-working, honest and industrious folks who kept to themselves. Not sure he ever met a Mormon missionary. But yeah, he was probably a fan of a religion encouraging multiple wives.